# Pipe jar output to file in python

Tags: java, python

I am running a jar file from python using something to this

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'tool.jar'])
```

I would then like to save the output to a file, but the issue is that the original java code has the output being sent to `System.err.println(output)`. I would love to modify the original java file, but this is not an option.

How can I send this output to a file? I have tried:

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'chattool.jar', '>', 'out.txt', '2','>','err.txt'])
```

as well as

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'chattool.jar', '&>', 'test.txt'])
```

but neither one redirects the output. Is it possible to do this within python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe stdout/stderr into a file using [Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

```
_stdout = open('/tmp/chattool.stdout.txt', 'w')
_stderr = open('/tmp/chattool.stderr.txt', 'w')

cmd = subprocess.Popen('java -jar chattool.jar', stderr=_stderr, stdout=_stdout, cwd=_cwd, shell=True)
cmd.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to accomplish this using

```
import subprocess
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
    subprocess.run(['java', '-jar', 'tool.jar'], stderr=f)
```